# Can the newest IPAD-pro run Ubuntu as a VM under an app such as VMware?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, ip-address

We just got a **new IPAD-Pro** and would like to run Ubuntu on it. Previous posts have very much negated this possibility, however the newest IPAD seems to have all of the speed needed; BTW, there is a VmWare app available for the iPad, which is where I successfully run Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro.  It would be interesting to understand why this is not possible, identifying what Apple might do in the future to make it possible. Perhaps it is a threat to the apps that it wants to sell...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like UTM (https://getutm.app/) to get a VM running on iOS or iPadOS. But this uses emulation which is slower than virtualization.

Yet you will need a bit of tinkering, with sideloading/jailbreaking, to get it up and running see (https://getutm.app/install/).

Apple A-Series SoC's do not support virtualization on iOS/iPadOS devices although with the new 2021 iPad's this might change since they include the Apple M1 SoC that supports virtualization.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  I looked into this a bit more and decided it didn't add enough value to my objects.  On a laptop it's no problem, but there are too many other reasonable solutions to pursue it further. RDH81